# Django ModelForm ValidationError not displaying on the webpage

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm learning the Django Framework, I though let me start using some of the django features instead of doing eveything again. I started to use model forms and also saw this `raise ValidationError` feature which will display if there are any errors.
I started off with creating a simple User Login and Registration form and it looks like this:

**Models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
import re, bcrypt


def check_uname(value):
    if not re.match('^[.a-zA-Z0-9_]+$', value):
        raise ValidationError('Invalid Username')   

def check_passwd(value):
    if len(value) < 8 and not re.search(r'[A-Z]', value) and not re.search(r'[a-z]', value) and not re.search(r'[0-9]', value):
        raise ValidationError('Invalid Password')

def login(uname, passwd):
    there = User.objects.filter(user_name=uname).values()
    if there:
        if bcrypt.hashpw((passwd).encode(), there[0]['password'].encode()) != there[0]['password'].encode():
            return  "wrong"
        else:
            return there

    else:
        return "wrong"

class User(models.Model):
      full_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
      user_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, validators=[check_uname])
      email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
      password = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[check_passwd])
      created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
      updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
import bcrypt
from django.db.models import Q

class loginForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['user_name', 'password']
        exclude = ['full_name', 'email']
        widgets = {
        'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
    }



class regForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label="Comfirm password", required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['full_name', 'user_name', 'email', 'password']
        widgets = {
        'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }

    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['password'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
            print "Passwords do not match"
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")
        else:
            user = User.objects.filter(Q(user_name=self.cleaned_data['user_name']) | Q(email=self.cleaned_data['email']))
            if user:
                print "Username or Email already in use"
                raise forms.ValidationError("Username or Email already in use")
            else:
                print ("hashing password")
                unhashed_passwd = self.cleaned_data['password'].encode()
                self.cleaned_data['password'] = bcrypt.hashpw(unhashed_passwd, bcrypt.gensalt())
        return (regForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from . import forms
from . import models
import bcrypt

def login(request):
    if 'user_id' not in request.session:
        context = {'loginForm':forms.loginForm, 'regForm':forms.regForm}

        if request.method == "POST" and 'password2' in request.POST:
            reg_Form = forms.regForm(request.POST or None)  
            if reg_Form.is_valid():
                print "It is inside valid"
                print errors
                reg_Form.save()

        else:
            form = forms.loginForm(request.POST or None)

            if form.is_valid():
                user_info = models.login(form.cleaned_data['user_name'], form.cleaned_data['password']) 
                if user_info == "wrong":
                    messages.error(request, 'Username or Password is invalid.')
                else:
                    request.session['user_id'] = user_info[0]['id']

        return render(request, 'index.html', context)

    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

**Template**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        {% load staticfiles %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
        {% load bootstrap3 %}
        {% bootstrap_css %}
        {% bootstrap_javascript %}
    </head>

    <body>

            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-top">
              <div class="container">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Ketan.io</a>
              </div>
            </nav>

        {% bootstrap_messages %}

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row col-md-6">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <h3><li>Login</li></h3>
                </ol>
                <form action="/login/" method="post" class="form-inline">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% bootstrap_form_errors loginForm %}
                    {% bootstrap_form loginForm show_label=False %}
                    {% bootstrap_button "Login" button_type="submit" button_class="btn-primary" %}
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="margin_left col-md-6">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <h3><li>Register</li></h3>
                </ol>
                <form action="/login/" method="post" class="form">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% bootstrap_form_errors regForm %}
                    {% bootstrap_form regForm show_label=False %}
                    {% bootstrap_button "Register" button_type="submit" button_class="btn-primary" %}
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong! I want the `ValidationError` to pop up on the HTML. I'm sure validations are working because I am also checking them with the help of print statements.
I'm very new to this and still learning. I might not use the best practices yet but will definitely get better with practice.

Regards and Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in your context

You are not sending the proper instances of your forms

```
context = {'loginForm':forms.loginForm, 'regForm':forms.regForm}
```

Both `loginForm` and `regForm` are your form classes, not instances. So, attach the forms to the context dict after initialize them

```
def login(request):
    if 'user_id' not in request.session:
        context = {}

        if request.method == "POST" and 'password2' in request.POST:
            reg_Form = forms.regForm(request.POST or None) 
            context.update({'regForm':reg_Form})


            if reg_Form.is_valid():
                print "It is inside valid"
                print errors
                reg_Form.save()

        else:
            form = forms.loginForm(request.POST or None)
            context.update({'loginForm':form})
            if form.is_valid():
                user_info = models.login(form.cleaned_data['user_name'], form.cleaned_data['password']) 
                if user_info == "wrong":
                    messages.error(request, 'Username or Password is invalid.')
                else:
                    request.session['user_id'] = user_info[0]['id']

        return render(request, 'index.html', context)

    else:
        return redirect('/')
```